# Reverse imagesc y-axis tick marks to go from positive to negative values

Tags: matlab, axis, cartesian-coordinates

I am using  imagesc on my image1 with is a 2023 x 2023 pixel image.

```
figure(1)
imagesc(-1016:1015, -1016:1015, image1);
```

I am atempting to create a cartesian coordinate axis on the image, however the y-axis has range goes from negative to positive instead of positive to negative. I have tried a few different ways to fix the problem but nothing is working.

Tried:

```
imagesc(-1016:1015, 1016:-1015, image1);
imagesc(-1016:1015, 1016:-1:-1015, image1);
imagesc(-1016:1015, 1016:1:-1015, image1);
imagesc(-1016:1015, -(-1016:1015), image1);
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');
```

How do you reverse the scale on the y-axis using imagesc?

Comment: you can also just use `flipud` \ `fliplr` on your image, can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the I had to do two things first I added a negative to the y-axis --> -(y-axis) and then I set the y-axis direction to normal. If I only did one the axis would look correct but the image was flipped across its horizontal midpoint.

```
figure(1)
imagesc(-1016:1015,-(-1016:1015),image1);
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
```

Comment: Note that `-(-1016:1015)` is *not* the same as `(1015:-1:-1016)`. Be sure you know which one you want. I recommend using `flipud(image1)` instead if your pixel indices are backwards from what you intend them to be.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `imagesc` function sets the `YDir` property to `reverse`. Try

```
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
```

Comment: Yes, but that flipped the image so I added a -(y-axis) and my image is right-side-up again!

Comment: @FireSky That means that your data is upside-down. Use `flipud(image1)` to fix that problem.  (By the way, I don't get notified when you update a comment on my answer, only when you create a new comment.)